# Enterprise Portal Web Parts not showing in Sharepoint for anonymous users

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, dynamics-crm, axapta, enterprise-portal

We have an enterprise portal site based on sharepoint, and we want to open it up for anonymous access.

However, dynamics ax web parts do not display when logging in as anonymous user, even though the Guest account has been set up, and correctly configured.

Other web parts (e.g. an image slideshow) appear correctly for anonymous users. Yet, the Quicklaunch web part doesn't work. The Guest account was given full admin access for testing purposes, and also shows as being Online when anonymous users are viewing the site.

No audience was set for any of the web parts.

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been resolved, there was another setting we had overlooked.

We forgot to enable Anonymous access in Enterprise Portal.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure your anonymous user has enough permission to use / get the desired rendering for the web part ? I don't know these "dynamics ax web parts" but the empty rendering might be the result of an exception (permissions) which prevent the webpart from being rendered properly.

Also, didn't you set any audience on the webpart(s) ? Check in the tool pane, at the bottom, if the webpart is not configured to be displayed to specific groups / audiences only.

Kindly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We're setting the guest account to have full permissions, and the web part is not being displayed to any specific group/audience.

Comment: Did you check the logs under 12/14 \ Logs ? There might be an error somewhere. Do you have the same issue on a vanilla team / collaboration site, with anonymous on and a sole webpart ?

Comment: Nothing much to go on in the logs, and we're not able to set up a vanilla site.

Answer (score 1):

Are they blank or do you get access denied?  If blank, do you use security trimmed controls in your master page.  If access denied, are you using a cache?  If you do IISReset, and make sure that the anonymous user is the first to connect to the page, does the web part work?  If you're using impersonation, and Guest doesn't have access to the file system, perhaps it cannot read from the cache directory.

Comment: The controls are blank, i.e. they just do not show. We are not using a cache.

Answer (score 1):

Is the ViewFormPagesLockDown feature disabled?